# Adding clickable buttons or links for side bar

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble adding links or buttons to my side bar dynamically. I'm trying to use JavaScript to add the appropriate amount of  elements or buttons(I don't know what is better). In essence this is used to make a JS quiz website where each of the buttons in the sidebar will jump you to the question(to make it more clear: Question 4 takes you to 4th question and so on)

This is my side bar:

```
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
      <a href="#">Question </a>
</div>
```

My JS trying to make the elements but failing to do so:

```
//add question numbers to the side bar
        function questionNav(){
            for(var i = 0; i < numberOfQuestions; i++){

                    document.getElementById("mySidenav").innerHTML = "Question " + (i+1) + "<br/>";
                //var newSideBarElm = "Question " + (i+1) + "<br/>";
                //document.getElementById("mySidenav").insertAdjacentHTML = ('beforeend',newSideBarElm);    

            }
        }
```

I've been trying numerous different methods but I can't get it to work and would greatly appreciate if someone was able to help me.

Here is the full code of the site in case you would like to see how I'm doing everything else: https://pastebin.com/hrSADLQy

Comment: You need to use something like this   https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_nodes.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your question and the code you provided i think you need to define a div with an onclick() property to make the corresponding question visible. That could be something like this (assuming you can access the number of questions inside this function):

```
function questionNav(){
    for(var i = 0; i < numberOfQuestions; i++){
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").innerHTML += "<div style='cursor:pointer' onclick=navigateToQuestion(" + (i+1) + ")/> Question " + (i+1) + "</div>";
    }
}
```

And then define a the onclick function "navigateToQuestion" to show the question that is passed as parameter, maybe could be somethink like this:

```
function navigateToQuestion(question){
    document.getElementById("question_" + currentQuestionInView).style.display = "none";
    currentQuestionInView = question;
    document.getElementById("question_" + question).style.display = "block";
}
```

Haven't tested the code but i think it should work.
Hope you get your problem solved :)

Comment: Thank you very much this helps greatly, The code correctly makes the amount of questions available but they aren't clickable. I'll try and troubleshoot as to why! Thanks again!

Comment: No problem! Maybe i missed some parenthesis or something like that when i assigned the onclick function.. If you find out the problem let me know :) also don't forget to mark the answer if you finally solved your question.

Comment: So i found the problem out, it was an added / the whole time. I also changed the divs to buttons. Not sure if that helped but I caught the syntax error afterwords. Thanks for the help

Comment: Aah i see.. Next time i will try to provide a fully working solution. Sorry for that!

Answer (score 1):

So assuming that I understand your question correctly, what you are currently doing is targeting the div with the id 'mySideNav' and overwriting its content by assigning a new value to its innerHTML attribute. What you should be doing instead is

1. Create a new anchor element
2. Use the innerHTML attribute to insert your desired value (i.e "Question N")
3. Append your newly created element to your 'mySideNav' div element.

I wrote a small [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/starchild94/cyau383y/1/) for you to see my answer in action, but will post my code below this answer for you to see as well.

```
// Grab and Store Element to append questions to
var mySideNav = document.getElementById('mySidenav');

// Designate number of questions
var numberOfQuestions = 10;

// Loop as many times as there are questions
for (let i  = 0; i < numberOfQuestions; i++) {

   // Step 1: Create a new anchor element 
   let newQuestion = document.createElement('a');

   // Assign href to whatever you want
   newQuestion.href = '#';

   // Step 2: Use the innerHTML attribute to insert your desired value
   newQuestion.innerHTML = 'Question ' + i + '<br>';

   // Step 3: Append your newly created element to your 'mySideNav' div element.
   mySideNav.appendChild(newQuestion);

}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much your example is very helpful,I'll try and implement a similar approach in my code! Thanks again